# Visual SVN Server Transaction log - Serialized hash missing terminator

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, smartsvn

I am using a svn server setup using - (Visual SVN Server in WindowsXP)
Now I got an error in my Smart SVN transaction log- (Used to checkout the content in SVN in Mac)

**-: E200002: Serialized hash missing terminator
svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn//!svn/bc/1045': 400 Bad Request ()**

I can see my revision upto 1042.  Now I can do commit, update and all other SVN operation. But cannot able to see the transaction log.

I think I had an issue with revision at : 1045 but I don't know what the error is and where I need to check.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the repository is corrupted. Do you have a backup? Restoring from a backup is the preferred way to solve this.

I assume that you run VisualSVN Server 2.5.9 (Subversion 1.7.9) or older and there was a power or a disk failure on the machine. Subversion 1.7.9 has a bug that can result into a corrupted repository if a power / disk failure occurs. The bug was fixed in Subversion 1.7.10 / VisualSVN Server 2.5.10.

See http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.7.10/CHANGES.

> - fix repository corruption on power/disk failure on Windows (r1483781)

Comment: @baherp I think I had this issue after I do a restore one month back.